# php - Create a var based on a var

Tags: php, var

How to get a var into a var, Example:

```
$gameid = 5;
$game{$gameid} = active;
```

So, I want var $game5 to be set to active.

How to do this?

Thanks.

Greetings. Jonathan

Comment: If you find you're assigning numbers to variables, then you probably have a prima facie case for using an array instead

Answer (score 2):

```
$gameid = 5;
${"game" . $gameid} = "active";

echo $game5; //Echoes Acive
```